# grep doesn't exclude directory, hangs

Tags: ubuntu, grep, ubuntu-14.04

I'm looking for files on my server containing the text string `"sometext"`, but I want to exclude searching in the `/var/www/sometext` folder (and its subfolders).

So I did the following:

`grep -rl "sometext" / --exclude-dir=/var/www/sometext`

However, there were 2 problems:

1. The results still contained files from the folder I wanted to exclude, and
2. `grep` eventually hangs (image below)

[image]

---

My questions:

1. Why would `grep` return files from within the folder I want it to exclude?
2. Why would `grep` hang, and also, after it hangs, how would I get the prompt back again?
3. Bonus question: how would adding a trailing asterisk in the excluded folder specification change the results `--exclude-dir=/var/www/sometext*`?

Answer (score 2):

Questions 1 and 3 are related and can be answered at a time. As per the `grep` man page (emphasis mine):

> --exclude-dir=DIR
>
> Exclude directories matching the **pattern DIR** from recursive searches.

So basically what you specify with that option is a **pattern** and not a directory itself, meaning `/var/www/sometext*` or even `/var/www/sometext/*` will expand and match any file/subdirectory of the one specified (the second is even more accurate, since the first one could match other directories whose name start with `sometext`.

Question 2 can be explained because you are probably `grep`ping inside the `/dev` directory, which contains all the system's devices and particularly there are some of them considered "infinite", like e.g. `/dev/zero`, so the command won't ever end. It's a good idea using `--exclude-dir` to match al special directories like `/dev`, `/sys` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but why was grep still searching within subfolders of `/var/www/sometext` when I asked it to exclude directories whose names contained that pattern?

Comment: Because it is not treated as a pattern itself, you need to determine exactly what you want to exclude, so in your case it is all files within that directory, so you would need to specify `/var/www/sometext/*`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I used `--exclude-dir=/var/www/sometext/*`, However it's returning results from subfolders of `/var/www/sometext`. Is `/var/www/sometext/*` supposed to be within curly brackets or something? I also tried `var/www/sometext/*`, without the leading `/`, same result.